# Install meter stops when installing apps in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-installation

As the title says, install meter stops when trying to install software. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I get into the software Center, I find the app I want, click to install, enter the admin password, it's starts installing and then the process meter stops at like 10% or something. Therefore I can't install any new apps using this Ubuntu software Center. I've had to do everything using .deb manual installs and using sudo commands. I really want to fix this Ubuntu software Center problem. Anyone had this problem before and know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there is a dialog box that opens behind the software center window that prevents installation from proceeding. When a selection is made, installation proceeds.

This isn't always the case, I've always been frustrated with how slow software center is.

---

Next, the synaptic package manager isn't quite as nice but it gets the job done and it's really fast. Run the following commands to install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Now, search your apps for **synaptic package manager**.

Search for and select packages. Then, click apply and always review the list before accepting the changes.

[help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)

---

Also, it isn't typically good practice to install packages using deb files unless the package is not available through apt-get.

You can search for packages using apt-get as well. Here's an example:

```
apt-cache search synaptic
```

To narrow the results, you can use grep to list results containing a keyword like in this example:

```
apt-cache search synaptic | grep "package manager"
```

Finally, install a package using the following command (this example installs synaptic):

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

To update your *list* of packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and to update all your packages:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```